# Turning off magit-mode commit formatting

Tags: git, emacs, magit

The recent-ish version of Magit (`M-x magit-version` says `magit-20131222.850`) I'm currently using enforces certain annoying properties on commit messages, and colors them oddly. Specifically, it auto-breaks lines at a certain length and colors the first one green.

Is there any way to disable this, and make it act like the old dumb commit message window? I don't see anything relevant-looking in `M-x customize-mode`, so I assume the solution will involve some `elisp`.

Comment: When you're in a commit buffer, if you do `C-h m`, what does it show as the major mode? What's the output of `M-x magit-version`?

Comment: @Chris - added version info to the question. `C-h m` names `git-commit-mode` as the major mode of the commit buffer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following to your `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'git-commit-mode-hook
          '(lambda () (auto-fill-mode 0))
          ;; append rather than prepend to git-commit-mode-hook, since the
          ;; thing that turns auto-fill-mode on in the first place is itself
          ;; another hook on git-commit-mode.
          t)
```

As for the font color, I suggest you move the cursor to the text of interest, do `M-x customize-face`, and use the dialog.

However, you could do something like this in raw elisp:

```
(set-face-foreground 'git-commit-summary-face "white")
```

(In general you can move the cursor to the text of interest and do `M-x describe-face` to learn what face it is you want to modify.)

Comment: Worked like a charm. The three faces I had to customize were `git-commit-nonempty-second-line-face`, `git-commit-overlong-summary-face` and `git-commit-summary-face`.

Comment: I'm running magit 2.6.0, and I had to use `(add-hook 'git-commit-setup-hook 'turn-off-auto-fill t)`.  Also, `(setq git-commit-summary-max-length 999)` will keep it from coloring text and warning you when your summary line is too long.

Answer (score 6):

In the latest magit versions (I'm using Magit 20190122.503) you need to use `git-commit-setup-hook` to make this work:

```
(add-hook 'git-commit-setup-hook 'turn-off-auto-fill
          ;; append to end of git-commit-setup-hook to ensure our hook trumps others.
          t)
```

Comment: Thanks! Quite weird how it automatically formats your text by default without even asking...